# Error with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I have a UITableViewController with static cells. In the first cell I have a uipickerView. (I have other things in the other cells, but I don't think it's relevent.) I tried to center the pickerView in the cell 2 ways. 1st - I added 4 constraints all around. That gave me an error and didn't display correctly when I ran it on the simulator. The 2nd way is, I added 2 constraints for the x and y. That also gave me an error.

Below is the error:

```
2015-01-18 15:47:49.533 myApp[1476:54966] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc24e9cb0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc24da620.centerX == UIPickerView:0x7fcbc24eb1e0.centerX>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc254d7e0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIPickerView:0x7fcbc24eb1e0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc24da620 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc2556c00 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIPickerView:0x7fcbc24eb1e0(600)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc25be170 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc24da620(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc24e9cb0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc24da620.centerX == UIPickerView:0x7fcbc24eb1e0.centerX>
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

It said the same thing for Y, but I cut it off so it would be more clear.

I'm a beginner as you can probably tell, so please don't be too harsh on me.

**Update**

I took away both constraints (x and y) and I added a constraint on the left and right. When I ran it, the pickerView was spread out as if it were a ipad, (probably 600) and it gave me the following error:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffcf1d76200 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffcf1d0a2d0.trailingMargin == UIPickerView:0x7ffcf1d78a60.trailing - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffcf1d529b0 UIPickerView:0x7ffcf1d78a60.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffcf1d0a2d0.leadingMargin - 8>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7ffcf1c74700 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIPickerView:0x7ffcf1d78a60(600)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffcf1dbf220 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffcf1d0a2d0(375)]>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffcf1d76200 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffcf1d0a2d0.trailingMargin == UIPickerView:0x7ffcf1d78a60.trailing - 8>
```

Comment: Which error is this, the first or the second way?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the new problem. The constraints work for me. See my again-revised answer.

Comment: The problem for you, obviously, is that `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint` which is trying to set your picker view to be 600 wide (and succeeding). But I don't know where that is coming from; I don't have one.

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of Xcode?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of xcode. by the way, I made the cell return a height of 163, and the pickerView is 162. Not sure if it makes a difference

Comment: No, we're doing width here. I'm sorry, I can't help any further because I can't reproduce the issue. I assure you (as I've said in my revised answer) that it works just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you anyway! I appreciate you taking the time to try and figure a solution.

Comment: Added another screen shot showing my constraints. Maybe you can see some difference between what we're doing?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy to read the list of constraints in the error message: it just takes a little practice. You have the following:

- The picker view is centered horizontally in its superview
- The picker view's left edge is at its superview's left edge
- The picker view's width is 600

It is easy to see, with a little thought, that those can be reconciled only if the cell is 600 pixels wide. But it isn't - which is what the fourth constraint in the list tells you:

- [But] the superview's width is 375

Now you're probably going to ask: how do I get out of this conflict? I didn't even create some of those constraints! I *think* the way to do it is to remove the "centered" constraint and just constrain the picker view's left edge *and right edge* to its superview. Thus its width will be determined by its superview's width instead of conflicting with it.

**EDIT** I tried it out and it works fine:

[image]

That is a single cell of a static table view running in the simulator. The picker view was added to the cell and I applied three constraints: top, left side, and right side. No issues appear in the console.

Here are the constraints and other info as shown in the Size inspector:

[image]

Comment: So what do I do to fix that? I don't want it to only be for iphone. I also want it for the ipad

Comment: By the way, @MikeSteevson, if you've got problematic constraints in Interface Builder, it warns you. The only way you could have gotten into this situation is by ignoring those warnings. Don't ignore them! There is absolutely no point running your project until you've gotten rid of the Interface Builder warnings about your constraints - no good can come of doing that.

Comment: You are right, that it should show a warning or something, but it didn't in here. ( I'm not sure why.) I understand what you wrote in the answer, but for some reason, it didn't help when I did what you wrote. I'll update my question so you can see the error it shows now

Comment: Cool thanks. If I have to, I'll try this out on my own machine.